# Silverlight: Override some autogenerated fields in a DataForm, while preserving the rest?

Tags: c#, silverlight, dataform

I have a DataForm that does 90% of what I need. I would like to add a few fields of my own. This [tutorial](http://wildermuth.com/2009/05/25/DataForm_Templates) provides an example of how to do this, but it looks like I need to override everything to do that. (I'd rather not have that extra bulk.)

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557951/silverlight-4-overriding-the-dataform-autogenerate-to-insert-combo-boxes-bound-to) looks like there might be a way by subclassing DataForm, but that seems kinda messy, and I'd like to stick to specifying the UI declaratively instead of procedurally.

Any other way to do this, or do I have to bite the bullet?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I found was, unfortunately, overriding the default dataform with one that includes support for the data annotations from vanilla WCF.

http://new.efficientcoder.net/2010/06/using-dataannotations-on-generated.html

It sounds like this is the approach may be the one you are trying to avoid, but I haven't found anything better.